# I'm a newbie to RN, I need a little guidance with @react-native-community/datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, react-native, datetimepicker

The issue is that, assume I'm selecting the following date and time
[image]
This is the code i have used to get this

```
 <DateTimePicker
          testID="datePicker"
          value={date}
          mode={'datetime'}
          is24Hour={true}
          // onChange={e => setDate(e.nativeEvent.timestamp)}
          onChange={e => {
            console.log('eee', e);
            console.log(new Date(e.nativeEvent.timestamp));
            setDate(new Date(e.nativeEvent.timestamp));
          }}
        />
```

Now, my issue is that, it's converting the selected time to UTC , all i want is to get the selected date and time irrelevant to the time zone user is in. I just want sept 5, 2023 8:49 AM
How do i get it ? I don't want to do time zone conversions as that will mess up my use-case, Is there a way to get the selected date and time ? or is there any other react-native module that is easier to work with ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the function [Date.UTC()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) instead of just `Date()`. This will treat all selected date-times relative to UTC-0, removing the need to handle the change. If converting it to string offsets the result to user's local timezone, you can use [getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

All this can be handled inside your `onChange` function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The component is already converting your datetime back to the user's local timezone before displaying it. If you would like to use `date` elsewhere in your application, you *must* handle the timezone. Datetimes do not exist (and should not exist) without a timezone attached which allows you to localize it for a user.

If you'd like to just display the datetime elsewhere in your app, try

```js
<Text>{date.toLocaleString()}</Text>
```

to get something like `9/2/2023, 10:28:02 PM`. This will localize the datetime string from UTC to the user's timezone for you.

Also, you can directly access the date from the `onChange` function like this and avoid creating new `Date` objects from timestamps:

```js
onChange={(e, selectedDate) => {
  setDate(selectedDate);
}}
```

Comment: so is it safe to assume that , irrelevant to the time-zone , I will always get the selected time and date from date.toLocaleString() ?

Comment: You will always get the selected date and time from `date` (via the `onChange` function's `selectedDate`). You can then represent that `Date`, or _any_ `Date` in the user's local time zone by using `.toLocaleString()`.